# How best to handle variable pricing during auction/sale

Tags: solidity, payable, auctions

I'm building a contract for running multiple auctions, each selling individual ERC721 tokens from an array of token IDs, and the price increases with each one sold (the properties of the sale is defined in advance). If sales are made rapidly, then some sales may fail if the eth sent to the contract is too low (i.e. if it was correct at the time the payment was invoked, but has since increased before the tx completes).

I'm trying to think through how best to handle these rapid price changes from a UX point of view. Some initial thoughts:

1. Require an amount of ETH greater than the expected price to cover any potential increase, then return the difference to the user's address.
2. Have the calling code control the price. (Obviously this is a little riskier, and would need to be carefully implemented to prevent abuse).
3. A blend of the two: E.g. Have the contract control the base price, and the calling code can securely provide the delta above the base price.

Note: In addition to the variable pricing on the contract, the UI must also display the next price. Obviously this cannot be 100% accurate due to the length/timing of transactions, but hoping to provide the best possible user experience.

Any input/other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!